# Iterating through nested list and skipping rows or columns

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I'm developping a windows chess app/game with python 3.7 and pygame as my first programming project. I already got quite far, but there is a problem that I tried solving for hours and can't figure out how to solve.

I have a nested list that stores the positions of my chess pieces on the board, which looks like that:

```
ppos = [
    ["br", "bkn", "bb", "bq", "bk", "bb", "bkn", "br"],
    ["bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp"],
    ["e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e"],
    ["e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e"],
    ["e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e"],
    ["e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e", "e"],
    ["wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp"],
    ["wr", "wkn", "wb", "wq", "wk", "wb", "wkn", "wr"],
]
```

Then I have a function that returns the colour of a piece in my nested list ppos:

```
def get_piece_colour(piece):
    blackpieceslist = ["br", "bkn", "bb", "bk", "bq", "bp"]
    whitepieceslist = ["wr", "wkn", "wb", "wk", "wq", "wp"]

    if piece in blackpieceslist:
        colour = "black"
    elif piece in whitepieceslist:
        colour = "white"
    elif piece == "e":
        colour = "e"
    return colour
```

Another function checks and highlights all possible moves for a piece that was clicked on by blitting a partially transparent green square (surface) on every square on the board that can be moved to.

Above mentioned function with working example white pawn:

```
def highlight_possible_squares(from_row, from_col, piece):
    pygame.draw.rect(green_highlight, ALPHAGREEN, green_highlight.get_rect())

    # white pawn
    if piece == "wp":
        for r in range(0, 8):
            for c in range(0, 8):

                to_row = r
                to_col = c

                square_x = to_row * square_size
                square_y = to_col * square_size

                square_xy_tuple = (square_x, square_y)

                from_to_row_dif = from_row - to_row
                from_to_col_dif = from_col - to_col

                # if on starting row, squares that are one and two squares in front get highlighted
                if from_row == 6:
                    if from_to_row_dif == 1 and from_to_col_dif == 0 and get_piece_colour(ppos[r][c]) == "e":
                        highlight_squares_lst.append(square_xy_tuple)
                    elif from_to_row_dif == 2 and from_to_col_dif == 0 and get_piece_colour(ppos[r][c]) == "e":
                        highlight_squares_lst.append(square_xy_tuple)
                    # diagonal move to destroy other pieces
                    elif from_to_row_dif == 1 and from_to_col_dif == 1 and get_piece_colour(ppos[r][c]) == "black":
                        highlight_squares_lst.append(square_xy_tuple)
                    elif from_to_row_dif == 1 and from_to_col_dif == -1 and get_piece_colour(ppos[r][c]) == "black":
                        highlight_squares_lst.append(square_xy_tuple)

                # if not on starting row, pawn can only move one square in front
                elif from_row < 6:
                    if from_to_row_dif == 1 and from_to_col_dif == 0 and get_piece_colour(ppos[r][c]) == "e":
                        highlight_squares_lst.append(square_xy_tuple)
                    # diagonal move to destroy other pieces
                    elif from_to_row_dif == 1 and from_to_col_dif == 1 and get_piece_colour(ppos[r][c]) == "black":
                        highlight_squares_lst.append(square_xy_tuple)
                    elif from_to_row_dif == 1 and from_to_col_dif == -1 and get_piece_colour(ppos[r][c]) == "black":
                        highlight_squares_lst.append(square_xy_tuple)

        for t in highlight_squares_lst:
            board.blit(green_highlight, (t[1], t[0]))
```

Now what I cant figure out how to do is the rook. The rook can move left, right, up and down, but it is not allowed to jump over pieces and move to the squares behind those.

This is what I have so far:

```
# white rook
if piece == "wr":

    for r in range(0, 8):
        for c in range(0, 8):

            square_x = r * square_size
            square_y = c * square_size

            square_xy_tuple = (square_x, square_y)

            if from_row == r and get_piece_colour(ppos[r][c]) == "e":
                highlight_squares_lst.append(square_xy_tuple)
            elif from_col == c and get_piece_colour(ppos[r][c]) == "e":
                highlight_squares_lst.append(square_xy_tuple)

    for t in highlight_squares_lst:
        board.blit(green_highlight, (t[1], t[0]))
```

An image example of how it looks at the moment when I click on the rook in the middle of the picture:

[image: highlight white rook moves]

So in this example the square left of the white pawn on the left, the squares right of the white pawn on the right and the square between the black queen and the black pawn should not be highlighted by my function.

Anybody could give me a hint of how to do it?

Thank you.

P.S. I know that propably most of my code can be improved a lot, but I'm a beginner and I'm trying to get better with time.

Comment: I assume we can calculate higlighted function according to the origin of the chosen piece. The rook that is chosen piece's position (3,3). We have four directions that it can be moved. For up direction, we could increase 1 to control y axis. For instance, (3,4) == 'e' paint and increase then control (3,5) if it is not 'e' then stop and keep control other directions like this.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but I still can't get it to work. Im running one for loop from the starting row to the top, one from the starting row to the bottom, one from the starting col to the right and one from the starting col to the left. I also added break to each for loop if the piece colour is not "e", but doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So partially thanks to shalom and partially by research I came up with a solution.

I tried going in all 4 directions by using 4 for loops and break those when I hit a piece/square that's colour is not "e".
What really did the job was the stage parameter of the range function.

```
# white rook
    if piece == "wr":

        for c in range(from_col + 1, 8):
            if get_piece_colour(ppos[from_row][c]) == "e":
                highlight_squares_lst.append((from_row * 100, c * 100))
            else:
                break

        for mc in range(from_col - 1, -1, -1):
            if get_piece_colour(ppos[from_row][mc]) == "e":
                highlight_squares_lst.append((from_row * 100, mc * 100))
            else:
                break

        for r in range(from_row + 1, 8):
            if get_piece_colour(ppos[r][from_col]) == "e":
                highlight_squares_lst.append((r * 100, from_col * 100))
            else:
                break

        for mr in range(from_row - 1, -1, -1):
            if get_piece_colour(ppos[mr][from_col]) == "e":
                highlight_squares_lst.append((mr * 100, from_col * 100))
            else:
                break

        for t in highlight_squares_lst:
            board.blit(green_highlight, (t[1], t[0]))
```

[image]